# Iterated integral over non-rectangular region problem.

Tags: calculus, integration

Could we integrate $S$, where $S$ is the region bounded between $y = 1$ and $y = x^2$ over the function $xy$ by taking $y$ constant?

I solve the problem by taking $x$ constant and get the result $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do the integral either way:

$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{x^2}^1 xy\; dydx$

Or

$\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}xy\;dxdy$

Comment: what is the characteristic of a region that can only be integrated in one way?